# Compare two fields in Rails ActiveRecord with aliases

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a DB with cryptic field names, so I have aliases for each of them:

```
alias_attribute :charge_duty, :aeaqst
.....
```

The task is to compare two fields with normal names (aliases) not select the records when they are equal.
Now, I do `where('aaayva <> aaa0va')`, what I have to change to use my aliases? I can do `where.not(charge_duty: 'value')`, but how to replace value with other field name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ActiveRecord select by field comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40793061/activerecord-select-by-field-comparison)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking something like this?

`ARClass.where.not(charge_duty: :other_field)`

Let me know if it helps

Comment: `other_field` will interpolate into 'other_field` string instead of cryptic fieldname

Comment: I though you said you were having alias_attribute for each of those so-called cryptic field names?

Comment: I have aliases for each attribute, but `.where.not(charge_duty: :other_field)` construction will transform into ...WHERE aeaqst != 'other_field'

Comment: So you mean you want: where aeaqst != other_fields value?

Comment: I mean `.where.not(charge_duty: :other_field)` => `WHERE aaayva != aaa0va`

Comment: What will happen if you just give like this .where.not(charge_duty: other_field)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128980/discussion-between-uday-and-meliborn).